# Find other numbers given a single number

Tags: java, loops

I want to create the rest of integer variables within the range 1 to 5 (inclusive) given that I have one of the numbers in between 1 to 5 (inclusive) already. 
So far, I simply used if statements to find the numbers however, it is very lengthy and I thought it would be possible using loops. I can't figure out how to do that so I need some help.
Here is my if statements code:

```
    int choice1=0; //This can be any number between 1 and 5 inclusive.
    int temp01 = 0, temp02 = 0, temp03 = 0, temp04 = 0;
    if(choice1 == 0){
        temp01 = 1;
        temp02 = 2; 
        temp03 = 3; 
        temp04 = 4;
    }
    if(choice1 == 1){
        temp01 = 0;
        temp02 = 2; 
        temp03 = 3; 
        temp04 = 4;
    }
    if(choice1 == 2){
        temp01 = 0;
        temp02 = 1; 
        temp03 = 3; 
        temp04 = 4;
    }
    if(choice1 == 3){
        temp01 = 0;
        temp02 = 1; 
        temp03 = 2; 
        temp04 = 4;
    }
    if(choice1 == 4){
        temp01 = 0; 
        temp02 = 1; 
        temp03 = 2; 
        temp04 = 3;
    }
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop and an array.

Comment: you mean `for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) if(i != choice) System.out.println(i);` ?

Comment: Could you instruct me on how to make the for loop? I can make an array however, the loop is the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: Your comment says "between 1 and 5 inclusive" but your code seems to indicate "between 0 and 4 inclusive". Which of the two do you mean?

Comment: ^Sorry. My mistake. I got the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer would be similar to what Sanjeev said, but my method would be this:

1. Choose a number,
2. Create an int array with 4 elements.
3. A for-loop that will go through 0-4.
4. Check on each iteration if the current number is the pre-selected number. If so, do nothing. Else, set the next unset number in the array equal to the current number.

Example below:

```
int numbers[] = new int[4];
int counter = 0;
int preselected = 0; //this would be set to anything from 0-4
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  if(i != preselected){
    numbers[counter] = i;
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

These steps might help you in writing code using array

1. Choose a Number
2. Create an array with 4 elements
3. Create a for/while loop which will iterate through 1 to 5
4. In loop compare if entered number is equal to the loop index/counter variable
5. If equal skip the number else add it to array and increment array counter
6. increment loop counter
7. Print Array

Some good tutorials reference for creation of loops

[Loop Control on Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

[Nuts and Bolts - For Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
int choice1 = 0;
int temp[] = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (i < choice1) {
        temp[i] = i;
    } else {
        temp[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] temp = new int[4]; //Here create an array of 4 integers
int choice1 = x; // x must be between 0 and 4 included
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    if(!(choice1 == i)){ 
       temp[j] == i;
       j++;
    } else if(choice1 != 4){
           temp[j] = i+1;
           i++;
           j++;
        } else {
            temp[j-1] = choice1-1;
        }
    }
}
```

this should work, if the choice is different !(choice1 == i) you assign the value of i in the position j, if it's equal, you want to skip that value, so you assign the next value to temp[j] and you go on with the loop
If the choice is 4 you would get IndexOutOfBoundsException so in that last case you assign the value of the previous number to your last element of the array